# While building rocket-tools dir (in Rocket Chip setup), getting "ar: illegal option combination" Error

Tags: unix-ar, rocket-chip

I am new to Rocket chip and trying to install rocket chip and execute simulation but while Creating rocket tool dir in Rocket chip setup as per README.md file, I am getting following error:

---

```
ar: illegal option combination for -r
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make: *** [libfesvr.a] Error 1
```

---

This error comes while executing ./build.sh command.

I am using Mac OS sierra 10.12.06.

`mac-vsanjay:rocket-tools vsanjay$ which ar`
`/usr/bin/ar`

I open build.sh and found that this error is coming during execution of

`build_project riscv-isa-sim --prefix=$RISCV` command.

I also tried to modify Makefile which calls "ar" command:

```
  ## Heading ##
    `$(AR) rcs -o $$@ $$^`
```

but this cmd `<build_project riscv-isa-sim --prefix=$RISCV>` generates and overwrites makefile.

Please suggest how to overcome with AR error.

Comment: The `ar` command is so old that it partially predates the "use a dash before the options" convention (`tar` does too).  That means you can use `ar rcs library …`.  However, the options reported do not list `-o` with the `ar -r` (`ar r`) option.  So, you need to ensure that you don't provide `-o` as well as the `rcs` options.  I'm not clear whether the back-ticks in the section marked `## Heading ##` are genuine or an artefact of attempting to use MarkDown to format the information.  It is unlikely that they should be part of a command line as shown, though.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your suggestion. But I can't modify Makefile which has ar command. build_project* command automatic generates makefile which has -o and rcs options. Any idea how to modify build_project* command which generate Makefile wo -o and rcs options.

Comment: Nope; I've not worked with the software.  You'll have to track down the code in the build project command that generates the incorrect invocation of `ar`.

Comment: Right Jonathan !. I am approaching the same way.

Comment: Friends, Can you help here who worked on Rocket-Chip?